# getChildren count in Firebase under a specific key, where a particular value exists

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I achieve this in Java, I set up my database in the format below, under Notification I have a child set up with a random key generated by Firebase and then I have other children under as below.

```
Notification ----
     dhsj37egshehhdeh----
        name - john
        userid - 939jjddehhd
        status - unread
     347747dhhshhdeh3----
        name - doe
        userid - 956jj53hdhhd
        status - read
```

I am trying to get children count where status is equal to unread.

I tried to use `reference.child("Notification").orderbyChild("status").equalTo("unread"){`
then i get children count.

But I am not getting the children count, as I assume first have to reference the child key then how do I get the children count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you're using the Java, the simplest way to achieve that would be:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference notificationRef = db.child("NotificationV2");
Query queryByStatus = notificationRef.orderByChild("unread").equalTo(true);
queryByStatus.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            long count = snapshot.getChildrenCount();
            Log.d("TAG", "count: " + count);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be the exact number of children your query returns. So please note that the key to solving this problem is the use of the [DataSnapshot#getChildrenCount()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getChildrenCount()) method.

**Edit:**

If you have changed the name of the field from "status" to "unread" and the value to be boolean, and the name `Notification` to `NotificationV2` then please check my updated code. Besides that, we cannot see the other 5 elements. However, if all the other elements exist at the exact same level, then the above code should definitely work.

Comment: Just implemented this but i was getting a wrong count, it gives 6 whereas i have only 3 child as a whole where status is equal to unread (which I changed to true (bolean)) here is screenshot of the implementation 
https://prnt.sc/1x1prJ4vNeeu  and my firebase database 
https://prnt.sc/LUwGgYsNFUmR

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Please also show all 6 elements. So please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Not as an image.

Comment: I did the edits properly and it worked perfectly I am getting the correct count, I appreciate the answer, it is easy.

Comment: You're very welcome, Osas.